Why is there a picture of Bill Cosby in Perry White's office?
In the movie, Superman II, there is a framed picture of comedian Bill Cosby in Perry White's office.


Why is there an obvious picture placement of Bill Cosby?  What is the significance of this?

Apparently in one of his early stand-up performances Cosby did a skit about Superman. It can be heard on his 1963 comedy album "Bill Cosby Is A Very Funny Fellow Right!" Whether this was the actual reason I don't know but it's the commonly stated one on most trivia sites (including IMDB).
